# How to pass data from Recyclerview to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView populated in a Fragment and I want to Launch a new Fragment and pass data from the adapter ,I try to use Bundles but it always give a null value this my Adapter Class

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Information> mList;
private FragmentCommunication mCommunicator;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Information> list,FragmentCommunication communication) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mList = list;
    mCommunicator=communication;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view,mCommunicator);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Information current = mList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(current.name);
    holder.job.setText(current.job);

    FragmentB fragmentB=new FragmentB();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("NAME",current.name);
    bundle.putString("JOB",current.job);
    fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView name;
    TextView job;
    FragmentCommunication mComminication;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, FragmentCommunication Communicator) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        job = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_gob);
        mComminication=Communicator;
        name.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mComminication.respond(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

and this is my new Fragment that I want to launch

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
TextView textview;
TextView textView2;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,container,false);

    textview= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    textView2= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_job);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();


        if (arguments!=null){
        String name= arguments.get("NAME").toString();
        String job= arguments.get("JOB").toString();
            textview.setText(name);
            textView2.setText(job);}

}
```

}

this is how I connect Fragment and recyclerview Adapter
with interface

```
public interface FragmentCommunication {
void respond(int position);
```

}

and this the Fragment where the recyclerview is populated

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerAdapter mRecyclerAdapter;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_fragment,container,false);

    mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    mRecyclerAdapter=new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),getData(),communication);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return view;
}

public static List<Information> getData() {
    List<Information>data=new ArrayList<>();
    String[] names={"ahmed","mohammed"};
    String[] jobs={"sacsd","csscs"};

    for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        Information current=new Information();
        current.name=(names[i]);
        current.job=(jobs[i]);
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
}

FragmentCommunication communication=new FragmentCommunication() {
    @Override
    public void respond(int position) {
        FragmentB fragmentB=new FragmentB();
        FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.dumper,fragmentB).commit();
    }

};
```

}

and my mainActivity class is just add the RecyclerViewFragment

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerViewFragment fragment=new RecyclerViewFragment();
    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.dumper,fragment).commit();
}
```

}

so what is the right way to launch fragmentB and pass the data from recyclerview Adapter to fragmentB

Comment: "I try to use Bundles but it always give a null value" Please show us what you tried.

Comment: Also, what data do you want to pass?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I edited the post now

Comment: Is `tv_gob` supposed to be `tv_job`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes it is ,do u any idea what is the problem?

Comment: I already told you how to do it. If you still have problems you need to tell us what they are and show the relevant code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

thank you guys for the answer,I solved the problem using an interface with String values to connect the adapter with the fragment that contains the recyclerview and the other fragment here is what I did exactly :
this is the interface

```
public interface FragmentCommunication {
    void respond(int position,String name,String job);
}
```

and this is the adapter

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Information> mList;
    private FragmentCommunication mCommunicator;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Information> list,FragmentCommunication communication) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mList = list;
        mCommunicator=communication;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view,mCommunicator);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Information current = mList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(current.name);
        holder.job.setText(current.job);

        FragmentB fragmentB=new FragmentB();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("NAME",current.name);
        bundle.putString("JOB",current.job);
        fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView name;
        TextView job;
        FragmentCommunication mComminication;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, FragmentCommunication Communicator) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            job = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_gob);
            mComminication=Communicator;
            name.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mComminication.respond(getAdapterPosition(),mList.get(getAdapterPosition()).name,mList.get(getAdapterPosition()).job);
        }
    }
}
```

the fragment that contains the recyclerview

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerAdapter mRecyclerAdapter;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_fragment,container,false);

        mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        mRecyclerAdapter=new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),getData(),communication);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }

    public static List<Information> getData() {
        List<Information>data=new ArrayList<>();
        String[] names={"ahmed","mohammed"};
        String[] jobs={"sacsd","csscs"};

        for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
            Information current=new Information();
            current.name=(names[i]);
            current.job=(jobs[i]);
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }

    FragmentCommunication communication=new FragmentCommunication() {
        @Override
        public void respond(int position,String name,String job) {
            FragmentB fragmentB=new FragmentB();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("NAME",name);
            bundle.putString("JOB",job);
            fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.dumper,fragmentB).commit();
        }

    };

}

this is the fragmentB where I get the Strings from the Adapter

    public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    TextView textview;
    TextView textview2;
    String name;
    String job;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        name=getArguments().getString("NAME");
        job=getArguments().getString("JOB");

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,container,false);

        textview= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.getName);
        textview2= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.getJob);
        textview.setText(name);
        textview2.setText(job);


        return view;

    }


}
```

Comment: where do i  get R.id.dumper?

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with kotlin, the solution is much simpler. 
[Original Answer here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/7p02h0/kotlin_how_to_send_data_from_recyclerview_adapter/dsdpdug)

pass the function `val itemClick: (Int) -> Unit` to your adapter.

```
class MyRecyclerViewAdapter(params , val itemClick: (Int) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
internal inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    ...
    itemView.setOnClickListener( {itemClick(layoutPosition)} )
  } 
}
```

In your fragment use the returned value `position`

```
val myAdapter = MyRecyclerViewAdapter(params) { position ->
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either creating a listener interface in the adapter or using regular old getters, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I used the interface ,put it only solve half of the problem,I can open the fragment with the interface but I cant pass the Data

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with using a `Bundle`. You just need to pass it to the `Fragment` by calling [`setArguments()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)). Then you retrieve the `Bundle` in your `Fragment` with [`getArguments()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()).

Note that instead of `mList.get(position).name`, you can do `current.name`. Similarly for `job`.

Another part of the problem is that you create FragmentB on two different places. In one place you also call setArguments() but do not show the fragment. In the other you show the fragment but do not call setArguments(). If you really need to do this from multiple parts of your code you should write a method to avoid these inconsistencies.

Comment: still give a null result !

Comment: @AhmedEzzat Please be more specific. What do you mean by "a null result"? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error and what line of your code causes it?

Comment: @Code_Apprentice if (arguments!=null) is always true in the FragmentB Class

Comment: @AhmedEzzat Please edit your question to show that code. Be sure top provide enough detail do we can understand what you are going.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Bundle to the fragment through the setArguments(Bundle args) method. Since you have not set arguments, the bundle you try to extract in your Fragment resolves to null.

Comment: I setArguments() but it is still null