# How to pass values from a RecyclerAdapter of an fragment to another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, location

I am trying to pass values from a fragment which contains a recycler view to another fragment which are all part of the bottombar.

I have tried using interface to achieve this, but my app crashes and shows a `NullPointerException`.

My first fragment contains a checkbox along with a Edit Text showing current Location, price and an image button which serves as a `DatePicker`.

When the user checks the checkbox he can enter the date into the `EditText` field from the image button.
The user can pick three dates into the `EditText` Fields.

> My question is how to make these entries (location,price and date)
>   pass to the third fragment?

I have taken reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420496/how-to-pass-data-from-recyclerview-to-fragment) to implement the interface.

Here is my code

**Textproperty1.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sumitroy.pitchads.TextProperty1_Schedule_Classes.TextProperty1_Schedule;
import com.example.sumitroy.pitchads.TimesofIndia.TOITextFragment;
import com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar;
import com.roughike.bottombar.OnMenuTabClickListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TextProperty1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomBar bottomBar;
    String test=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_property1);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar appbar = getSupportActionBar();
        appbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        appbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        bottomBar=BottomBar.attach(this,savedInstanceState);
        bottomBar.noNavBarGoodness();
        bottomBar.noTabletGoodness();
        bottomBar.noResizeGoodness();
        bottomBar.hideShadow();
        bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottombar_textproperty, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {

                if(menuItemId==R.id.textproperty_bottombaritem1)
                {
                    TextProperty1_Schedule f=new TextProperty1_Schedule();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TextProperty1_Schedule.class);
                    intent.putExtra(test,"check");
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.textframe,f).commit();
                }
                else if(menuItemId==R.id.textproperty_bottombaritem2)
                {
                    TextProperty1_EditText f=new TextProperty1_EditText();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.textframe,f).commit();
                }
                else
                {
                   TextProperty1_ConfirmAd f=new TextProperty1_ConfirmAd();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.textframe,f).commit();


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Intent getSupportParentActivityIntent() {
        String from=getIntent().getExtras().getString("from");
        Intent newintent=null;
        if(from.equals("FAV"))
        {
            newintent=new Intent(this,TOITextFragment.class);
        }
        return newintent;
    }

}
```

**TextProperty1_Schedule.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sumitroy.pitchads.R;
import com.example.sumitroy.pitchads.TextProperty1;
import com.example.sumitroy.pitchads.TextProperty1_ConfirmAd;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TextProperty1_Schedule extends Fragment {
    TextView textView;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION=1;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<TextProperty1_Schedule_Location>scheduleLocationList;
    int imageid[]={R.drawable.location_show};

    public TextProperty1_Schedule() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview;
        rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_property1__schedule, container, false);
        textView=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.yourCity);
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            try
            {
                textView.setText(herelocation1(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Not Found!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        scheduleLocationList=new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=1;i<=15;i++)
        {
            if(i==1)
            {
                TextProperty1_Schedule_Location sl = new TextProperty1_Schedule_Location("Bangalore", "1000", " "," "," ", false,imageid[0]);
                scheduleLocationList.add(sl);
            }
            else if(i==2)
            {
                TextProperty1_Schedule_Location sl = new TextProperty1_Schedule_Location("Jamshedpur", "250", " "," "," ",false,imageid[0]);
                scheduleLocationList.add(sl);
            }
            else if(i==3)
            {
                TextProperty1_Schedule_Location sl = new TextProperty1_Schedule_Location("Indore", "100", " "," "," ", false,imageid[0]);
                scheduleLocationList.add(sl);
            }
            else if(i==4)
            {
                TextProperty1_Schedule_Location sl = new TextProperty1_Schedule_Location("Mumbai", "450", " "," "," ", false,imageid[0]);
                scheduleLocationList.add(sl);
            }
            else if(i==5)
            {
                TextProperty1_Schedule_Location sl = new TextProperty1_Schedule_Location("Goa", "450", " "," "," ", false,imageid[0]);
                scheduleLocationList.add(sl);
            }
            else
            {
                TextProperty1_Schedule_Location sl = new TextProperty1_Schedule_Location("Goa", "450", " "," "," ", false,imageid[0]);
                scheduleLocationList.add(sl);
            }
        }
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mAdapter = new TextProperty1_CardViewScheduleAdapter(scheduleLocationList,communication);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String[] permissions,int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        try
                        {
                            textView.setText(herelocation1(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Please Switch On Your Location!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No Permission granted!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public String herelocation1(double lat,double lon)
    {
        String currcity="";
        Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addressList;
        try
        {
            addressList=geocoder.getFromLocation(lat,lon,1);
            if(addressList.size() > 0)
            {
                currcity=addressList.get(0).getLocality();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return currcity;
    }

TextProperty1_CardViewScheduleAdapter.FragmentCommunication communication=new TextProperty1_CardViewScheduleAdapter.FragmentCommunication() {
    @Override
    public void respond(ArrayList<String> locattion_confirm, ArrayList<String> price_confirm, ArrayList<String> dates1_confirm, ArrayList<String> dates2_confirm, ArrayList<String> dates3_confirm) {

        TextProperty1_ConfirmAd fragmentB=new TextProperty1_ConfirmAd();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Location", String.valueOf(locattion_confirm));
        bundle.putString("Price", String.valueOf(price_confirm));
        bundle.putString("Dates1", String.valueOf(dates1_confirm));
        bundle.putString("Dates2", String.valueOf(dates2_confirm));
        bundle.putString("Dates3", String.valueOf(dates3_confirm));
        fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
    }
};

}
```

**TextProperty1_CardViewScheduleAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sumitroy.pitchads.R;
import com.example.sumitroy.pitchads.TextProperty1_ConfirmAd;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Sumit Roy on 06-Apr-17.
 */
public class TextProperty1_CardViewScheduleAdapter  extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<TextProperty1_CardViewScheduleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public ArrayList<String> location=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String>price=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String>dates1=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String>dates2=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String>dates3=new ArrayList<String>();
    private FragmentCommunication mCommunicator;

    public int day,month,year;
    int imagebuttonclick=0;

    private List<TextProperty1_Schedule_Location> stList;


    public TextProperty1_CardViewScheduleAdapter(List<TextProperty1_Schedule_Location> schedule_locations,FragmentCommunication communication) {
        this.stList = schedule_locations;
        this.mCommunicator=communication;

    }

    // Create new views
    @Override
    public TextProperty1_CardViewScheduleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                 int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.textproperty1_list_schedule_card, null);

        // create ViewHolder

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView,mCommunicator);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        final int pos = position;

        viewHolder.tvLocate.setText(stList.get(position).getLocation());

        viewHolder.tvPrice.setText(stList.get(position).getPrice());

        viewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(stList.get(position).isSelected());

        viewHolder.chkSelected.setTag(stList.get(position));
        viewHolder.img.setImageResource(stList.get(position).getUrl());


        viewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                //Click Event for check box

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                TextProperty1_Schedule_Location contact = (TextProperty1_Schedule_Location) cb.getTag();
                contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                stList.get(pos).setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                imagebuttonclick=0;
                /*Toast.makeText(
                        v.getContext(),
                        "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                                + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */

                viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Click event for image button
                        imagebuttonclick+=1;
                        if(imagebuttonclick==1)
                        {
                            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Clicked once",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                            day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            day=day+1;
                            year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            Context context=v.getContext();
                            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(context, 0, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                                    String selected_date=" " + i2+ "/" + i1 + "/" + i;
                                    //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),selected_date,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    viewHolder.dates.setText(selected_date);
                                    String getlocation,getprice,getdate1;
                                    getlocation=viewHolder.tvLocate.getText().toString();
                                    getprice=viewHolder.tvPrice.getText().toString();
                                    getdate1=viewHolder.dates.getText().toString();
                                    if(getdate1.length()!=0)
                                    {
                                        location.add(getlocation); //Pass this value to a different fragment
                                        price.add(getprice);//Pass this value to a different fragment
                                        dates1.add(getdate1);//Pass this value to a different fragment

                                    }


                                }
                            },year,month,day
                            );
                            //Will set datepicker dialog from current date
                            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
                            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
                            datePickerDialog.show();

                        }
                        else if(imagebuttonclick==2)
                        {
                            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"More Than once",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                            day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            day=day+2;
                            month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            Context context=v.getContext();
                            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(context, 0, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                                    String selected_date=" " + i2+ "/" + i1 + "/" + i;
                                    //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),selected_date,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    String getdate2;

                                    viewHolder.dates2.setText(selected_date);
                                    getdate2=viewHolder.dates2.getText().toString();
                                    if(getdate2.length()!=0)
                                    {
                                        dates2.add(getdate2); //Pass this value to a different fragment
                                    }


                                }
                            },year,month,day
                            );
                            //Will set datepicker dialog from current date
                            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
                            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
                            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,+1);
                            datePickerDialog.show();
                        }
                        else if(imagebuttonclick==3)
                        {
                            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"More Than once",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                            day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            day=day+3;
                            month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            Context context=v.getContext();
                            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(context, 0, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                                    String selected_date=" " + i2+ "/" + i1 + "/" + i;
                                    //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),selected_date,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    String getdate3;

                                    viewHolder.dates3.setText(selected_date);
                                    getdate3=viewHolder.dates3.getText().toString();
                                    if(getdate3.length()!=0)
                                    {
                                        dates3.add(getdate3); //Pass this value to a different fragment
                                    }

                                }
                            },year,month,day
                            );
                            //Will set datepicker dialog from current date
                            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
                            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
                            datePickerDialog.show();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Can Enter Ads only for three days",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            imagebuttonclick=0;
                        }


                    }
                });
                if(viewHolder.chkSelected.isChecked()==false)
                {
                    viewHolder.dates.setText(" ");
                    viewHolder.dates2.setText(" ");
                    viewHolder.dates3.setText(" ");
                }
                TextProperty1_ConfirmAd fragmentB=new TextProperty1_ConfirmAd();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Location", String.valueOf(location));
                fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);

            }

        });
        mCommunicator.respond(location,price,dates1,dates2,dates3);
        TextProperty1_ConfirmAd fragmentB=new TextProperty1_ConfirmAd();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Location", String.valueOf(location));
        bundle.putString("Price", String.valueOf(price));
        bundle.putString("Dates1", String.valueOf(dates1));
        bundle.putString("Dates2", String.valueOf(dates2));
        bundle.putString("Dates3", String.valueOf(dates3));
        fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);

    }

    // Return the size arraylist
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvLocate;
        public TextView tvPrice;
        public EditText dates;
        public EditText dates2;
        public EditText dates3;
        public ImageButton img;
        public CheckBox chkSelected;
        FragmentCommunication mcommunication;


        public TextProperty1_Schedule_Location singlestudent;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView,FragmentCommunication communicator) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemLayoutView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
            tvLocate = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
            tvPrice = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            img=(ImageButton)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
            dates = (EditText) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvDates);
            dates2=(EditText)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvDates2);
            dates3=(EditText)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvDates3);
            mcommunication=communicator;

        }

    }

    // method to access in activity after updating selection
    public List<TextProperty1_Schedule_Location> getStudentist() {
        return stList;
    }

    public interface FragmentCommunication {
        void respond(ArrayList<String> locattion_confirm,ArrayList<String> price_confirm,ArrayList<String> dates1_confirm,ArrayList<String> dates2_confirm,ArrayList<String> dates3_confirm);
    }
}
```

**TextProperty1_ConfirmAd**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TextProperty1_ConfirmAd extends Fragment {
    TextView textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5;
    ArrayList<String>get_location;
    ArrayList<String>get_price;
    ArrayList<String>get_dates1;
    ArrayList<String>get_dates2;
    ArrayList<String>get_dates3;


    public TextProperty1_ConfirmAd() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        get_location=getArguments().getStringArrayList("Location");
        get_price=getArguments().getStringArrayList("Price");
        get_dates1=getArguments().getStringArrayList("Dates1");
        get_dates2=getArguments().getStringArrayList("Dates2");
        get_dates3=getArguments().getStringArrayList("Dates3");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view;
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_property1__confirm_ad, container, false);
        textView1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView4=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView5=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        textView1.setText((CharSequence) get_location);
        textView2.setText((CharSequence) get_price);
        textView3.setText((CharSequence) get_dates1);
        textView4.setText((CharSequence) get_dates2);
        textView5.setText((CharSequence) get_dates3);
        return view;

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your question contains a lot of code that is probably not necessary for illustrating the issue. Please, consider minimizing the amount of code to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

For transfer data from fragments you should using Bundle. In your code I see that you put in bundle String (method public void respond), but in method onCrerate you call method getStringArrayList(). You call different methods and you get NullPointerException.

Comment: I have used Bundle as you suggested but it doesn't show any values in the edit Text fields.  Here is the code that i used..                      Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null)
        {
            get_location=bundle.getStringArrayList("Location");
            get_price=bundle.getStringArrayList("Price");
            get_dates1=bundle.getStringArrayList("Dates1");
            get_dates2=bundle.getStringArrayList("Dates2");
            get_dates3=bundle.getStringArrayList("Dates3");

        }

Comment: The value of the bundle is coming as null

Comment: Try to replace getStringArrayList to getString or in method respond  replace bundle.putString() to bundle.putputStringArrayList()

Comment: Change in method respond bundle.putString to bundle.putputStringArrayList()

Comment: Ya i changed but still nothing appears at the fragment.

Comment: Is fields get_price, get_location and other required null?

Comment: No they are not required Null..The values in these fields get populated through the edit texts and textfields in the recycler view. The dates are accepted from the date picker through an image button placed in each of the recycler views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [greenrobot/EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Register EventBus in all those fragment where you need an event. To get event **@Subscribe** a method with a required model. And perform your action within **runOnUIThread()**. I think your objective will be achieved. And remember one thing, don't forget to unregister EventBus when Fragment/Activity is destroyed.

Follow these steps-

Create a Bus Model

```
public class BusModelAdapterItems {
   private ArrayList<String> stringArrayList;

   public BusModelAdapterItems(ArrayList<String> stringArrayList) {
       this.stringArrayList = stringArrayList;
   }

   public ArrayList<String> getStringArrayList() {
       return stringArrayList;
   }
}
```

In your fragment put the codes-

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}

@org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe
public void onAdapterUpdate(final BusModelAdapterItems items) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do what you want
            // items.getStringArrayList();
        }
    });
}
```

From your Adapter please put this code-

```
// the array list that adapter holds and you want to pass to the fragments
EventBus.getDefault().post(new BusModelAdapterItems(arrayList));
```

Comment: I implemented the greenbot/EventBus but couldn't to pass the data to other fragment. Inside my recycler adapter of fragment A I have used EventBus.getDefault .postSticky(Arraylist<String>) method and in the Fragment C I have used the subscriber method and tried to receive the values using the object of my event class. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @SumitRoy Please pass a Model rather than ArrayList<String>. Set the ArrayList<String> as a field of your model. It should work.

Comment: Can you please give me a hint as how to pass an model? Don't mind I am new to android development.